# convert character back to POSIXct datetime

Tags: r, date, character

I wrongly stored the result of Sys.time() as type character. E.g.,  "2014-05-05 10:52:11 CEST" is converted to "1399279910.87737". How can I get the time back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric("1399279910.87737"), origin="1970-01-01")
```

The difference ought to be because of the rounding in the string representation. You could try playing with `origin` to make it match if the difference of a few seconds is a problem.